# C++ CLI Wrapper BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

So have an issue that has been driving me crazy.

I have a C++ CLI app which is wrapping a C Library so it can be accessed in C#

I have a solution with the C++ Project, and a NET5.0 console application which is referencing it. The console app runs absolutely fine with no issues.

I am currently trying to package the wrapper up as a Nuget package, which has lead me to this current point.

Unless the wrapper is directly referenced by the console app it will not run, giving me a BadImageFormatException. Now i know this is normally an issue of mixing 32 bit and 64 bit, but both are set to 64 bit.

To further test this, i got the console app running, and as expected the wrapper DLL's appeared in the console app output folder. I then removed the wrapper as a reference, and simply referenced the DLL's directly. So at this point it is using the exact same DLL it was previously, but i now get the exception.

The only other strange thing i see is that when it throws the exception, it is trying to load the DLL with a version of 0.1.2.3 which is absolutely not a version that we are using.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

ijwhost.dll needed to be included as well